# If I have a collection of hashes with the same key and values, how do I add another value together?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I've assigned these rows to hashes:

```
other_id: 1,amount: 9290,id: 1
other_id: 2,amount: 2262,id: 1
other_id: 3,amount: 9588,id: 2
other_id: 4,amount: 1634,id: 2
```

How do I add together the `amount` values for a specific `id`, so for `id: 1`, I need the `total = 9290 + 2262`?

Even better, if I had a large collection of these, how would I write code so that it would find the id number with the maximum value of total if total is the sum of all amount instances for a specific id number?

Comment: What do `other_id` and `id` mean? Are they related, and is either of them the key for the hash?

Comment: Please write your code in a pseudo code and explain in more details. Neither your code nor your question make any sense

Comment: Say each row is a hash and I have all rows in an array. other_id doesn't matter to me. I just want to look at amount and id and make sure it adds each amount for the same id OR make a code that looks through the whole file and recognizes which id number has the greatest total of amounts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom. We need to see an example of your effort: That means seeing code or evidence of your searching for solutions. As is it looks like you want us to write it for you, which is off-topic. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input looks like this:

```
array = [{id: 1, amount: 9290, other_id: 123}, {id: 1, amount: 1234, other_id: 30}, {id: 2, amount: 4444, other_id: 456}]
```

#### Q1

```
specific_id = 1 # or whatever you are looking for
sum = array.inject(0) do |sum, hash|
  sum += hash[:amount] if hash[:id] == specific_id
  sum
end
```

#### Q2 part 1: calculate the sums per id

```
sums = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |sums, hash|
  sums[hash[:id]] += hash[:amount]
  sums
end
```

#### Q2 part 2: find id/sum for max sum

```
max = sums.inject(sums.first) do |max, pair|
  pair.last > max.last ? pair : max
end
```

Comment: Rather than rely on `inject` for this, look at [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). It results in cleaner code because you don't have to return a value at the end of the block.

Comment: Usually i prefer each_with_object as well. But IMHO it's not a good match here because you can only alter the object, not re-assign in the block. Would make first and last piece of code less straightforward. The second piece of code would looked better though. But i chose to use the same method in all three parts for consistency.